# Do not add TITLE as heading to body when exporting org file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

This export option:

```
#+TITLE: My title
```

Does two things:

1. adds a meta tag on the document's `head`: `<title>My title</title>`
2. adds a heading at the start of the generated `content` `div`: `<h1 class="title">My title</h1>`

I want 1 but do not want 2. Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: You posted the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633910/do-not-add-title-as-heading-to-body-when-exporting-org-file) on Stack Overflow at the same time, and with a different user name.  Please don't do that.  People on this site don't automatically know what's happening on Stack Overflow and vice-versa, so won't know about comments and answers.

Comment: @Dan: The different username is an artifact (I changed my username Stack Exchange wide a couple of weeks ago, but it didn't work). I posted the same question in two places because I was not sure what was the best place to do it. You must concede that it is a bit confusing!

Comment: @jeckyll2hyde: Please do try to get all your accounts under the same name.  I'd suggest you delete the question on one or the other sites, although topically, it probably makes the most sense to keep it here.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the title by providing the appropriate CSS setting.  For example, add this line to your file (and hit `C-c C-c` to activate the change):

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css"> <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ .title { display: none; } /*]]>*/--> </style>
```

or set the `org-html-head` variable.
Here's the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support).